# How to fix error: Can't find string terminator "^@" anywhere before EOF?

Tags: perl

I got the error when try to run:

```
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.8.9/bin/perl -I/home/kes/work/projects/perl_libs/t/lib -I/home/kes/work/projects/perl_libs/t/../lib -d:DbInteract="t();q" -e "sub t {
return ( 1, undef, undef, 2 );
}
sub a {
my @list =  ( 1, undef, undef, 2 );
return @list;
}
1;
"
Can't find string terminator "^@" anywhere before EOF at /home/kes/work/projects/perl_libs/t/lib/Devel/DbInteract.pm line 15.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

What should I change to fix error?

Comment: The error is reported in the library, on its line 15. Can you show the relevant part? Also, you seem to be redefining a sub imported from it -- Is that what you intend to do, to redefine a sub from a loaded package?

Comment: https://github.com/KES777/Devel-DebugHooks/blob/master/t/lib/Devel/DbInteract.pm#L15

Answer (score 3):

The library you are calling is producing the error message. The [source line](https://github.com/KES777/Devel-DebugHooks/blob/master/t/lib/Devel/DbInteract.pm#L15) is

```
15:  my $endline = $1 // ';';
```

Your old Perl (5.8.9) does not support the `//` operator.

Comment: It would greatly improve this answer to include the line where that's present. As it stands, there's no indication in the question as to the nature of the problem.

Comment: Ah! Good catch.  Now I'd suggest to explain it a little, as Sobrique says.

Answer (score -1):

Try escaping your `@` symbols (so you have `\@list`).
Alternatively, change your script capture from double to single quotes. eg

```
... DbInteract="t();q" -e 'sub t { ..... } 1;'
```